# responsive table (no more tables) with ASP DataGrid asp:BoundColumn

Tags: asp.net, webforms, responsive

I am new to .NET. I am converting an existing HTML and asp.net website into responsive. I converted an ASP DataGrid into responsive using the no more tables approach and it is **working perfectly except that column headers are overlapped**. The DataGrid columns are elements like:

```
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="M_DATENAME" HeaderText="Day"></asp:BoundColumn>
```

and some of these columns contain `<span>` elements, therefore in the small screen sizes when the headers are added before td(s), these columns get overlapped.

So I tried two ways:

1. As per the [Udemy course](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud893/lessons/3581758575/concepts/35678795280923)  using `data-title` or `data-th` attribute:

   `no-more-tables td:before { content: attr(data-title); }`

However, the problem is that asp BoundColumn has no attribute called `data-title` or `data-th`

2. Second way is adding headers manually based on the [example](https://codepen.io/team/css-tricks/pen/wXgJww?editors=1100) -> problem with it: Some of the columns are set to be Invisible and visible in certain conditions only. So at some point these headers text get overlapped.

So what could be the solution to my problem?

Or how can I add the `BoundColumn HeaderText` as a value of the `content` css property instead of the `data-title` or `data-th`.

Comment: I am afraid you won't be able to achieve the desired result with the `DataGrid`. As you noticed, it generated its own markup and it usually it is not suitable for responsive design. In such cases I used a <`asp:Repeater>` where one has total control on the generated markup.

Comment: thanks for your response. I managed to do it with BoundColumn , however, I am stuck with TemplateColumn as it contains many elements inside its ItemTemplate like <asp:Label and  <asp:HyperLink. I will give it a try...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the problem. Actually the problem was caused from the DataGrid columns that have null values (empty), therefore these cells were not displaying while the headers were displaying and thus overlapping with next cells. I did the following to achieve that:
**1)** I added `<ItemStyle CssClass="headerStyle5"/>` for each BoundColumn and TemplateColumn
**2)** Then in the CSS, instead of adding titles with absolute column position, I referenced columns using the headerStyle name I added in step 1 as the following:

```
#no-more-tables td[class="headerStyle1"]:before { content: "Date"; }
#no-more-tables td[class="headerStyle2"]:before { content: "Day"; }
#no-more-tables td[class="headerStyle10"]:before { content: "Remarks"; }
```

**3)** in the VB.NET, I wrote below code to loop through all empty cells and add a label with just space which will case the cell to show

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To DataGrid1.Columns.Count - 1

    If e.Item.Cells(i).Text.Trim Is Nothing Or e.Item.Cells(i).Text.Trim = "" Then
        Dim sosoLabel As New Label
        sosoLabel.Text = "<label>&nbsp;</label>"
        e.Item.Cells(i).Controls.Add(sosoLabel)

    End If
Next
```

and now it is working perfectly :)